# D3 Force Layout Graph load data from file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I took this code off the web and it works correctly. I need to load the data from a json instead of the data being coded into the page. Being new to this, I decide to first simply take the original data and put it in a json file and call the file. I can't seem to get it to work. I get a blank section where the graph would go and all I get from debugger is "mutating the prototype of an object will cause you code to run slowly", which I get with the original code so that's not it.

Here is the section of the original code

```
function loadImage(){
 if(LoadData){
root = {
"name": "Daniel Vinod", "imageURL":"images/root.png","id":"1",
"children": [
 {"name": "Abraham Aaron", "imageURL":"images/user1.png","id":"2",
 "children":[{"name": "Joseph Titus", "imageURL":"images/user3.png","id":"3"},
              {"name": "Herold Enoch", "imageURL":"images/user4.png","id":"4"}]},

 {"name": "Samuel Goliatf", "imageURL":"images/user7.png","id":"5", 
"children":[{"name": "Enoch Titus", "imageURL":"images/user2.png","id":"6"},
             {"name": "Quintus Titus", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"7"}]},

 {"name": "Absalom Dauid", "imageURL":"images/user2.png","id":"8" ,
"children":[{"name": "Abraham Shalom", "imageURL":"images/user4.png","id":"9"},
           {"name": "Elisha Titus", "imageURL":"images/user6.png","id":"10"}]},

{"name": "Daniel Goliatf", "imageURL":"images/user3.png","id":"12",
"children":[{"name": "Quintus Titus", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"13"},
          {"name": "Enoch Titus", "imageURL":"images/user1.png","id":"14"},
          {"name": "Elisha Titus", "imageURL":"images/user6.png","id":"15",
            "children":[ {"name": "Enoch Absalom", "imageURL":"images/user1.png","id":"11"}]}]},

{"name": "Enoch Shalom", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"16",
"children":[{"name": "Absalom Joseph", "imageURL":"images/user7.png","id":"17"},
          {"name": "Shalom Joseph", "imageURL":"images/user4.png","id":"18"},
      {"name": "Quintus Titus", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"7"}]}
]
};

force = d3.layout.force()
.on("tick", tick)
.size([w, h]);

vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);
  update();
 LoadData = false;
}
}
```

I swapped the data for this

```
function loadImage(){
  if(LoadData){
root = d3.json("data2.json", function(error, graph) {
 if (error) throw error; 

  force = d3.layout.force()
.on("tick", tick)
.size([w, h]);

vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);
  update();
 LoadData = false;
}); 
}
}
```

And created a data2.json file:

```
{
"name": "Daniel Vinod", "imageURL":"images/root.png","id":"1",
"children": [
  {"name": "Abraham Aaron", "imageURL":"images/user1.png","id":"2",
  "children":[{"name": "Joseph Titus", "imageURL":"images/user3.png","id":"3"},
          {"name": "Herold Enoch", "imageURL":"images/user4.png","id":"4"}]},

  {"name": "Samuel Goliatf", "imageURL":"images/user7.png","id":"5", 
  "children":[{"name": "Enoch Titus", "imageURL":"images/user2.png","id":"6"},
          {"name": "Quintus Titus", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"7"}]},

  {"name": "Absalom Dauid", "imageURL":"images/user2.png","id":"8" ,
  "children":[{"name": "Abraham Shalom", "imageURL":"images/user4.png","id":"9"},
          {"name": "Elisha Titus", "imageURL":"images/user6.png","id":"10"}]},

  {"name": "Daniel Goliatf", "imageURL":"images/user3.png","id":"12",
  "children":[{"name": "Quintus Titus", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"13"},
          {"name": "Enoch Titus", "imageURL":"images/user1.png","id":"14"},
          {"name": "Elisha Titus", "imageURL":"images/user6.png","id":"15",
            "children":[ {"name": "Enoch Absalom", "imageURL":"images/user1.png","id":"11"}]}]},

  {"name": "Enoch Shalom", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"16",
  "children":[{"name": "Absalom Joseph", "imageURL":"images/user7.png","id":"17"},
          {"name": "Shalom Joseph", "imageURL":"images/user4.png","id":"18"},
          {"name": "Quintus Titus", "imageURL":"images/user5.png","id":"7"}]}
]
}
```

Note, no brackets, so it's not a true json but it doesn't work with the brackets either. Again, no error, just a white space where the graph should be. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Well, does the error you're throwing show up in the console? Can you `console.log(graph)`?

Comment: yes, I looked it up and it seems to be a bug in Firefox and I get it when the original code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root` is a variable in the original which points to the json object, which I suspect gets picked up and used in the `update()` function. In your 2nd example, you've defined `root` so it points to the json loading function, whereas `graph` is the pointer to the loaded json object. Rename `root` as `jsonFunc` and set `root = graph;` within the json loading function in your 2nd example, see if that works. If not, it's make a jsfiddle time.

Comment: Well, the images aren't there because I only have the json, but --> https://jsfiddle.net/xw0ckkeL/2/ - within the json loading func, make root to be graph like so, `root = graph;` (it wouldn't have worked just renaming in the function parameter as root would have been local in scope to just the function so that's my bad) - and rename the json loading function to anything other than `root`;

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close but couldn't quite get it.